# Case statement in Kusto query

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a Big list of codes in my table and I have silenced/excluded some of them by using !=

I want to check a condition for a specific error code like below. and also want other codes I have in the tables.

```
exceptions
| extend A_= tostring(customDimensions.A)
| extend B_ = tostring(customDimensions.B)
| where B_ != '21000' //exclude
| where B_ != '30000' //exclude
| where B_ != '40000' //exclude
| where B_ == "80000" 
    and A_ != "abcd" 
    and A_ != "wxyz"
```

The problem with using  B_ == "80000" with "and" operator is, it is only outputting a list of code 80000 that doesn't have those 2 string which is what I wanted. but I also want to output other codes that I haven't excluded in the query.

So far I have tried using a case statement like the below;

```
| where error_code_ != case(B_ != "80000", A_ != "abcd" , A_ != "wxyz")
```

But this isn't working as I have expected. Not sure what's wrong with the query or if there is a better solution to it.

Comment: Your example use of the `case` statement is incorrect; it uses alternating `if-then` parameters for a chained test of values and results. You probably wanted the `has_any` function. See the docs for [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/casefunction) and [has_any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-anyoperator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `or` operator:

```
exceptions
| extend A_= tostring(customDimensions.A)
| extend B_ = tostring(customDimensions.B)
| where B_ != '21000' //exclude
| where B_ != '30000' //exclude
| where B_ != '40000' //exclude
| where (B_ == "80000" and A_ != "abcd" and A_ != "wxyz") or B_ !="80000"
```

Comment: works like a charm. never knew we can nest statements in () like that. Thnks a lot @Ivan Yang